# Kanapes IDE for Couch DB

Tags: couchdb

I am trying to use kanapes IDE to connect my Couch DB 
But It is showing error like serve/ port is incorrect 
I am able to connect to the same using Couch console (port is 8091)
Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Could you please tell us how you actually connecting to you CouchDB, is it localhost one or remote one? When you type host name address in the input field, please make sure you type it without protocol prefixes, so it should be like localhost not http://localhost and so on.

Comment: @Skitsanos , I have tried both ways (with and without protocol prefix) my server is a remote machine , I can Access it over web like http://servername:8091 but using this tool when I tried adding server, it shows a warning 'Server address or port is incorrect'

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem.

- Remote server, I cut and paste just the hostname from my browser (that can connect) without the protocol or port
- I set the port to 443
- I checked the SSL box

The only thing I can add is that it's signed with self-signed cert for a different hostname.